# to replace line in the same text file without flushing out the other contents in java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I want to replace some content, no the entire content of the file with my content to be written in its place.

I wrote the following code in java :

```
        String update = "Pooja" + "," + "20" + "\n";
        try{
            File file = new File("Test.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


            String rline,rline1;
            while((rline = br.readLine())!=null){

                System.out.println(rline);

                if(rline.contains("Pooja") == true){
                    rline1 = rline;
                    rline = rline.replace(rline1,update);
                    System.out.println(rline);
                    break;
//                  System.out.println(score);
                }
            }
            br.close();
            FileOutputStream bw = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bw.write(rline.getBytes());

            bw.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

My file is like this :

```
Pooja,10
Priya,20
Riya,30
```

I want to update the file as :

```
Pooja,20
Priya,20
Riya,30
```

But when I ran the code, it flushed all the contents with only contents as :

```
Pooja,20
```

I tried many stackoverflow links but nothing helped. Please Help. I am new to this.

Comment: You are only writing the bytes of `rline`, which is the line containing "Pooja", as you break the reading loop after it. Create the output stream earlier and write the lines that do not contain "Pooja" the way they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a .properties file instead, class Properties.

Nice tutorial code [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

The file will be a bit differently.

```
Pooja=20
Priya=20
Riya=30
```

And

```
Properties userProps = new Properties();
Path userFile = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/userdata.properties");

void loadUserProps() {
    try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(userFile,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        userProps .load(in);
    }
}

void saveUserProps() {
    try (BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(userFile,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        userProps .store(out, "-- " + new Date());
    }
}

loadUserProps();

String old = userProps.getProperty("Pooja", "0");
int n = Integer.parseInt(old) + 10;
userProps.setProperty("Pooja", Integer.toString(n));

saveUserProps();
```

This looks less artificial, using an existing key-value container.

I made the file use UTF-8, so the full Unicode range can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what has been pointed by others already, you can achieve this by using a find/replace in a text editor, or using sed (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

Clearly I lack the context in which you are writing this program, but keep an open mind in terms of available tools if you problem is only text replace.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
File file = new File("Test.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("Pooja")) {
            line = "Pooja,20";
        }
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```